# How to delete androidTest & test folders for ever that not show up when creating new app

Tags: android, android-studio

I know it would be waired! but this is a question for me that How can I delete androidTest & test folders that creates automatically when you create an app in Android Studio?

Actually, I just want to have a main folder and I don't need these 2 folders anymore.(I mean forever and also by default, for next apps that I will make)

I hope to exist a way that I can set this(for example in setting) so whenever I create an app, I just see the main folder.

Unfortunately, this question or the same question doesn't exist here, so I to be forced to ask this.

I'll really appreciate if you can help me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I delete androidTest & test folders that creates automatically when you create an app in Android Studio?

Um, you just delete them.

> I mean forever and also by default, for next apps that I will make

There is no supported means of doing that.

> I hope to exist a way that I can set this(for example in setting) so whenever I create an app, I just see the main folder.

Don't create a project from the new-project wizard. Instead, copy an existing project into a new directory and adjust your files from there.

Comment: Tnx for your answer. but Are you sure there is nothing a way we can removing these 2 folders by default & forever?

Comment: @M.Barandov: You could build your own IDE, I suppose. That seems like a lot more work, though. :-) What gets created for a new project or module is driven by the IDE and is *partially* configured by templates. While you can modify the templates, that's not documented or supported, and those changes will get overwritten with a new Android Studio release. Plus, AFAIK, the choice of directories to create is not part of the templates.

Comment: @tnx I understood. ;)